# How to call on a class using 3 functions?

Tags: python, class, methods

I would like to create a Python class with 3 functions.

- Function 1 will ask the user to input one number.
- Function 2 will ask the user to input another number.
- Function 3 will multiply function 1 * function 2 and return to the product.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_x(self):
        x = int(input('What is the first number?: ')

    def get_y(self):
        y = int(input('What is the second number?: ')

    def mult_XY(self):
        return x * y
```

When I try calling on the class I get `'y' is not defined`.

I tried using the following code:

```
num = Product(x, y)
print(num.mult_XY)
```

Comment: With this approach, you need `self.` for every variable.

Comment: Even out your parenthesis, if you don't close the `int()` statement, it will throw an error: `y = int(input('What is the second number?: ')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working solution. Compare it to your current solution and spot the differences. After the following code snippet, I will highlight concepts you need to research in order to understand this program better.

Here is a correct version of your code (note: there is potentially more than one solution):

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def get_x(self):
        self.x = int(input('What is the first number?: '))
        return self.x
    
    def get_y(self):
        self.y = int(input('What is the second number?: '))
        return self.y

    def mult_XY(self):
        return self.x * self.y

p = Product()
x = p.get_x()
y = p.get_y()
result = p.mult_XY()
print('RESULT of {} * {} = {}'.format(x, y, result))
```

Is this the best answer? No. Depending on the specifics of your program, the structure of the code could be different.

You have gaps of knowledge on the following concepts:

- Objects and classes in Python
- Functions in Python
- Variables and scoping in Python

In order to understand better, you need to learn more about the fundamentals of Python. Here is a good resource to get you started: https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction.html

After reading that, you will be able to not only answer this question, but also set the foundation for your programming knowledge. Don't give up and wish you the best.

Comment: There is an issue with your code. While initializing `Product` class, it needs `x` and `y`.

Comment: I like the way you coded this... however, I received and error on p = Product()

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments 'x' and 'y'. Perhaps I did something wrong. I tried to copy and paste the code.

Comment: @TonyMontana Updated, see edit

Comment: @AbleArcher, as per your code, initialize `Product` class with values of `x` and `y`. Or if not  needed, remove the `x` and `y` from `__init__` method.

Comment: @AbleArcher Updated the code, try now, should work

Comment: It looks like you just need to add one more parenthesis in the final line of code. This worked great @geralt0! Thank you very much for your time and explantation.

Comment: @AbleArcher Oops, good catch! I updated the answer with the final parenthesis.  You're very welcome!  Enjoy the Python programming journey and have fun learning!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you forgot to use keyword `self` in function definition. There are lot of mistakes in your code.
I think this is the correct version of your code:

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_x(self):
        self.x = int(input('What is the first number?: '))

    def get_y(self):
        self.y = int(input('What is the second number?: '))

    def mult_XY(self):
        return self.x * self.y
```

And this is how you should check it working:

(Updated Version)

```
x = 10
y = 5
num = Product(x, y)
num.get_x()
num.get_y()
print(num.mult_XY())
```

Answer (score 1):

To reference anything stored in the current object you need to use `self.` like you did in the init function to originally save the values.

Example:

```py
class Product:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_x(self):
        self.x = int(input('What is the first number?: '))

    def get_y(self):
        self.y = int(input('What is the second number?: '))

    def mult_XY(self):
        return self.x * self.y
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but you might need "x" and "y" to be the inputs within the class.

If so, use `classmethod`s:

```
class Product:
    @classmethod
    def get_x(self):
        self.x = int(input('What is the first number?: '))
        return self
    @classmethod
    def get_y(self):
        self.y = int(input('What is the second number?: '))
        return self
    @classmethod
    def mult_XY(self):
        return self.x * self.y
```

Ex:

```
>>> Product.get_x().get_y().mult_XY()
What is the first number?: 3
What is the second number?: 4
12
>>>
```

Comment: Today I have learned something new. Method chaining with classmethod. Never thought about it before.

Comment: @TonyMontana Yeap! Great! It's useful sometimes.

Comment: This code worked perfectly @U12-Forward! Thank you so much for your response. I will learn a great deal from this. =)

Comment: @AbleArcher If my answer may have helped you, feel free to mark this as accepted by clicking the check mark (✔️), also feel free to upvote with the triangle pointing up. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information about accepting and upvoting answers.

Comment: I have never used @classmethod before. I have learned a great deal from this and will begin to study it. Thank you so much sir for your time and help! =)

Comment: This user has been a member for three years - no need to tell them to accept/upvote your answer - they probably know.